# Do GNU GCC compilers only accept "<filename>.a" files as libraries?

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, codeblocks, glew

So, basically what I am asking is, if GNU GCC compilers recognize only ".a" files as library files, the reason why I am asking this is because, I have linked 3 library files in my codeblocks cpp project, two of the library files have ".a" extension, the last has a ".lib" extension. When I try to build the project, this is this the error I get:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in OpenGl_GLFW (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -Wall -g -Idependencies\include -Idependencies\include
-IC:\Users\Mubarak\Documents\Programming\Cpp\OpenGl_GLFW\dependencies\include -c C:\Users\Mubarak\Documents\Programming\Cpp\OpenGl_GLFW\dependencies\lib\glew32s.lib -o obj\Debug\dependencies\lib\glew32s.o
g++.exe -Ldependencies\lib -Ldependencies\lib -LC:\Users\Mubarak\Documents\Programming\Cpp\OpenGl_GLFW\dependencies\lib -o bin\Debug\OpenGl_GLFW.exe obj\Debug\dependencies\lib\glew32s.o dependencies\lib\libglfw3.a dependencies\lib\libglfw3dll.a obj\Debug\src\main.o   -lopengl32.a dependencies\lib\glew32s.lib dependencies\lib\libglfw3.a -lopengl32.a dependencies\lib\glew32s.lib dependencies\lib\libglfw3.a
g++.exe: warning: C:\Users\Mubarak\Documents\Programming\Cpp\OpenGl_GLFW\dependencies\lib\glew32s.lib:
linker input file unused because linking not done
g++.exe: error: obj\Debug\dependencies\lib\glew32s.o: No such file or directory
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) 1
error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

so it looks like there is trouble with the .lib library file, I started programming in visual studio Community, over there, the .lib file works............. so am starting to get a sense "library files only work with a particular compiler if the same compiler was responsible for creating them" i just want to be sure of this.

If so, why do different compilers produce library files with different extensions ?
And, do different compilers compile differently ? do different compilers create different machine code ?

Comment: I think you are missing the important part : **error:
obj\Debug\dependencies\lib\glew32s.o: No such file or directory**, so look why glew32s.o is absent.

Comment: There's no source file to build into an object file. Therefore there's no object file to use when linking. What do you think providing `...\lib\glew32s.lib` as source input would do?

Comment: What is the first g++ command expected to do? There is no input and it would write a file called `glew32s.o` which also doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AProgrammer yeah, the file does not exist, the thing is i have a .lib file, i tried using g++.exe to compile the .lib file, it failed, compiling needs .cpp or .c files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude idk, is there a point you are trying to make ? all i know is .lib files are library files that have already been compiled from a source, so i dont see why i need another source file.

Comment: @BDL which line exactly, as you can tell, i am not an expert in this stuff so i would appreciate it if i was spoon feed with answers.

Comment: the `.lib` is presumably a visual studio static library which wont work with gcc anyway

Comment: A library is something you *link* with. A stativ library is a collection of object files, so they have indeed already been compiled. So why compile the already compiled object file again? That doesn't make sense. You should build ***your*** source files into object files. Then you link your object files with other object files, and libraries, to create the executable program.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thanks, the answer i was looking for.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i dont compile it (i mean i do but not in the way you are thinking), i am not the one generating and running those command line statements, i just added the .lib file into my project in codeblocks then i went to project -> build options -> linker settings  , under linker libraries, i add the name of the library i wanted to link to my project, the process is automated, i just hit build, Alan Birtle has confirmed my suspicion, thanks by way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the .lib is presumably a visual studio static library which wont work
> with gcc anyway

found this in one of the comments, which means, visual studio used .lib libraries and gcc uses .a libraries

Answer (score 0):

".lib" libraries are dynamic type and the compiler assumes that it is not the programmer's job to insert them into the code. These libraries, as well as the ".dll" are inserted by the compiler itself during the compilation process. There are other extensions that you can use, like ".h" for example.

Comment: And about the compilers creating different machine code, yes thy do. But only when are used on different OS, for example, compiling on a Windows 32bits and a 64bits is totally different machine codes